# ServiceStack Redis client : remove all objects

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

I want to remove all objects that are stored in Redis via the ServiceStack Redis client.
I tried to use the Remove method with "*" as a key but it is not ok.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to clear all data on the Redis instance you can use:

```
redis.FlushAll();
```

Or if you just want to clear the DB you're on:

```
redis.FlushDb();
```

Comment: is there a method to flush only the keys within the .WithPrefix("prefix")?